# Getting celery task id

Tags: django, celery

I have made something like that

```
@app.task
def some_task()
    logger.info(app.current_task.request.id)
    some_func()

def some_func()
    logger.info(app.current_task.request.id)
```

So I receive normal id inside some_task, but it equals to None inside some_func. How can I get real task id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bind the task and pass the request around rather than relying on a global.

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def some_task(self)
    logger.info(self.request.id)
    some_func(self.request)

def some_func(celery_request=None)
    # celery_request is optional assuming you're using it elsewhere.
    if celery_request:
        logger.info(celery_request.id)
```

Comment: Thanks. It`s strange because current_task is available inside child function