# Celery - How to get the task id for a shared_task?

Tags: django, celery

I've looked at questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302320/celery-get-task-id-for-current-task) one and a dozen [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55183581/getting-celery-task-id). But none of them seems to be working.

I've a shared_task like this one, which doesn't return anything:

```
@shared_task
def rename_widget(widget_id, name):
    w = Widget.objects.get(id=widget_id)
    w.name = name
    w.save()
```

I've tried `self.request.id` and `current_task.request.id` but they both returned **None**.
My celery version is 5.0.4 and django version is 3.1.1. I'm using Rabbitmq as messenger.

Comment: and you've tried:  rename_widget.request.id?

Comment: Yes, of course. Returns None.

Comment: sorry, need more context: 1. have you imported the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a setup issue, or how you're calling the task. Without knowing more of the context, it is hard to say--perhaps you need to bind the method? I've sketched that out that solution:

tasks.py

```
from celery import shared_task
from demoapp.models import Widget

    @shared_task(bind=True)
    def rename_widget(self, widget_id, name):
        print(self.request.id) 
        w = Widget.objects.get(id=widget_id)
        w.name = name
        w.save()
```

views.py or somewhere else:

```
from tasks import rename_widget

result = rename_widget.delay(1, 'new_name')
```

If that's not the issue, I'd check out the full working Django example setup for ideas, found here: https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/examples/django/

Comment: It was how I was calling it. Thank you.